# Steps to create inhouse distribution in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am having enterprise account. Can anyone tell the clear steps to distribute the package via URL.

Comment: You could use our application, that will be available in a few weeks. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps for building are [pretty well documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH11-SW3). I found this [shinydevelopment.com blog post](http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/over-the-air-ios-provisioning-and-distribution/) helpful in creating an OTA distribution.